# Get EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification when app is in background (iOS)

Tags: nsnotificationcenter, eaaccessory

In my '`viewDidLoad'in` `ViewController.m`, I am registering to the `NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter` with '`EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification`' and '`EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification`'
When my app is active in foreground, I get the notification, and respond in accessoryDidConnect. all works OK.
But, when app is in background, how can I get such notification?

```
('EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification' and 'EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification')
[Code below]
```

Thanks a lot.
Dan

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
                                               object:nil];    

    [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/MonitoringEvents.html), it's not possible:

> If your app is suspended in the background when an accessory
>   notification arrives, that notification is put in a queue. When your
>   app begins running again (either in the foreground or background),
>   notifications in the queue are delivered to your app. Notifications
>   are also coalesced and filtered wherever possible to eliminate any
>   irrelevant events. For example, if an accessory was connected and
>   subsequently disconnected while your app was suspended, your app would
>   ultimately not receive any indication that such events took place.

But it would be interesting if someone proved me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 12.1.4, plug in the relay cable with iPhone and DSLR Camera when app is in foreground, then switch app into background mode, unplug the relay cable and switch app back into foreground, you will receive the accessoryDidDisconnect notify via EAAccessory's delegate methods.